# Save Each Multiline Grep Output To Array Record

Tags: regex, bash

I am parsing XML with regex. It is well known so there is no need to worry about escaping etc and proper XML parsing.

grep is returning multiple lines and I want to store each match to a file.

However, I either get each line in between my tags in my array `array=( $list )` or I get the whole output `array=( "$list" )`.

How can I loop over each match from grep?

My script currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

list=$(cat result.xml|grep -ozP '(?s)<tagname.*?tagname>')
array=( "$list" )
arraySize=${#array[@]}
for ((i = 0; i <= $arraySize; i += 1)); do
  match="${array[$i]}"
  echo "$match" > "$i".xml
done
```

Comment: Can you show sample data from `result.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36090401/1566221), the upcoming version of `grep` will change the meaning of the `-z` flag so that both input *and output* are NUL-terminated. So that will automatically do what you want, but it's only available *today* by downloading and building grep from the git repository.

Meanwhile, a rather hackish alternative is to use the `-Z` flag which terminates the *file name* with a NUL character. That means you need to print a "filename", which you can do by using `-H --label=`. That will print an empty filename followed by a NUL *before* each match, which is not quite ideal since you really want the NUL *after* each match. However, the following should work:

```
grep -ozZPH --label= '(?s)<tagname.*?tagname>' < result.xml | {
  i=0
  while IFS= read -rd '' chunk || [[ $chunk ]]; do
    if ((i)); then
      echo "$chunk" > $i.xml
    fi
    ((++i))
  done
}
```

Comment: you meant `((++i))` ? ;-) . Wow, `-ozZPH` ... `grep` has grown up since Sun 4 days ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter- wow, lots of typos. Hopefully fixed, thanks. Maybe -PHozZ would be cooler :)

Comment: `-PHozZ` LOL, another advantange to having more options on `grep` ;-) .

Answer (score 0):

Directly cat you lines to a while loop

```
my_spliting_command | grep something | while read line
do
    echo $line >myoutputfile.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` to grab all the matches first, and then use `awk` to save each matched pattern into separate files (e.g. file1.xml, file2.xml, etc):

```
cat result.xml | grep -Pzo '(?s)(.)<tagname.*?tagname>(.)' | awk '{ print $0 > "file" NR ".xml" }' RS='\n\n'
```